# Streaming bunch of files in Java

Tags: java, spring, stream

I have a `List<File> folder` in `java` and each of these files need to be processed line by line. In spring batches, there is a `read` function that returns an `object` that needs to be processed and `null` if the batch needs to be terminated. I want to implement this using streams. I could only map each of these files to a stream. How do I read the file line by line using streams? Also each line need to be processed using some logic before sending it out to the processor

My code so far

```
folder.map((file) -> new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))).map((csv) -> csv.iterator()).
```

I am expecting to get a final iterator on which I can just do the following

```
public Object read() {
   if(iter.hasNext() {
      return iter.next();
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is ur code ?

Comment: there you go @javaguy

Comment: Does the iterator contain lines from each file separately or all files together ?

Comment: `Files.lines` read the file line by line

Comment: All files together

Comment: I think concatenation of all file streams will work here